# Search column for multiple strings but show faults Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am searching a column in my data frame for a list of values contained in a CSV that I have converted to a list. Searching for those values is not the issue here.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('output2.csv')
hos = pd.read_csv('houses.csv')
parcelid_lst = hos['Parcel ID'].tolist()
result = df.loc[df['PARID'].isin(parcelid_lst)]

result
```

What I would like to do is once the list has been searched and the data frame is shown with the "found" values I would also like to print or display a list of the values from the list that were "unfound" or did not exist in the data frame column I was searching.

Is there a specific method to call to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You mean like `df.loc[~df['PARID'].isin(parcelid_lst)]` or am i misunderstanding? Im also not convinced that pandas generates a `set` with `isin` so `parcelid_lst = set(hos['Parcel ID'].tolist())` may _significantly_ improve performance

Answer (score 0):

Adding the tilde does the opposite. Maybe that would get all the values that are not part of the `parcelid_lst`

`not_found = df.loc[~df['PARID'].isin(parcelid_lst)]`

Hope that helps.

Comment: So this kind of works however, the column "PARID" is 530,000+ rows. It seems what your function is doing is showing me the remaing PARID's, excluding the ones that do not appear in the parcelid_lst.

Answer (score 0):

After reconsidering my question and thinking about it a little bit differently, the solution I found is to turn all the values in the data frame in the 'PARID' column into a list. Then compare the 'parcelid_lst' to it.

This resulted in a list of all the values that did not exist in the data frame but did exist in the 'parcelid_lst'

```
df = pd.read_csv('output2.csv')
allparids = df['PARID'].tolist()
hos = pd.read_csv('houses.csv')
parcelid_lst = hos['Parcel ID'].tolist()
list(set(parcelid_lst) - set(allparids))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would also like to print or display a list of the values from the
>   list that were "unfound" or did not exist in the data frame column I
>   was searching.

You don't need to subset your dataframe for this. You can filter your *series* for items not found in your specified list (or series) and then use [`pd.Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
not_found = df.loc[~df['PARID'].isin(hos['Parcel ID'].unique()), 'PARID'].unique()
```

As above, it's a good idea to make your `hos['Parcel ID']` an array of *unique* values if you expect duplicates to exist in the series.